# MySQL GROUP BY with preference

Tags: mysql, group-by

is it possible to use GROUP BY with a preference for records?

For instance I have whole bunch of contact data that may or may not contain all info - in a CSV sense if might look like this:

```
Test User, Address1, Address2, test@test.com  
, , , test@test.com
```

If I was to GROUP BY email, I would love to extract the more relevant record.

Hope that makes sense?

Yours,
Chris

Comment: What do you mean by "more relevant record" ?  Another row with an identical email?  Or another column?  Or?

Comment: Hi, supposed those two rows above where in the database - I'd want to pull out the one with contact information rather than the row with empty fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use an aggregate function for getting the more 'relevant' record for each email. 
I think this query would get you the best result:

```
SELECT emailAddress, max(concat(fullName,',',address1,',',address2))
FROM table
GROUP BY emailAddress
```

It will return the richest row for each email address but all data will be returned within one string (comma-separated) so you will have to parse it somehow. 
If performance is no issue and you'd like to get a normal result set in separate fields then you could go with one:

```
SELECT table.emailAddress, fullName, address1, address2 
FROM 
table JOIN 
    (SELECT emailAddress, 
       max(concat(fullName,address1,address2)) as bestRowInOneString
    FROM table
    GROUP BY emailAddress
    ) bestRowsSubQuery 
 ON 
   concat(table.fullname,table.address1,table.address2) = bestRowsSubQuery.bestRowInOneString
   AND table.emailAddress = bestRowsSubQuery.emailAddress
```

Answer (score 1):

For each email, this query will select the record with the most fields set:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    (
        SELECT  DISTINCT email
        FROM    mytable
        ) mi
JOIN    mytable mo
ON      mo.id =
        (
        SELECT  id
        FROM    mytable mf
        WHERE   mf.email = mi.email
        ORDER BY
                username IS NULL + address1 IS NULL + address2 IS NULL DESC
        LIMIT 1
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

GROUP BY SUBSTRING(field,N);

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean, but in some (most?) SQL dialects you can combine `GROUP BY` with `CASE` logic:

```
GROUP BY case when col1 = 'x' then col1 else col2 end
```

(like I said, I'm not sure if that is valid for MySql).

**EDIT**: if that's not valid for MySql, you could always extract this bit of logic

```
GROUP BY case when col1 = 'x' then col1 else col2 end
```

into a view and `SELECT` from that view, `GROUP`ing on the column containing the logic e.g.

```
select * from
(
   select ....
   , (case ....) as logic_col
   from ...
) x
group by logic_col
```